# Why Visual Studio 2013 Intellisense negelect the definition when "__declspec(selectany)" is defined as a macro?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

My C (**not C++**) project contains 3 files:

(Lib.h)

```
extern const int X;
```

(Lib.c)

```
#define GLOBAL_REMOVE_IF_UNREFERENCED __declspec(selectany)
GLOBAL_REMOVE_IF_UNREFERENCED const int X = 123;
```

(Main.c)

```
#include "Header.h"
void main()
{
    int Y = X; // <=== Press F12 to jump to the definition of X
}
```

I press F12 on `X` in `Main.c` in the hope to jump to the definition of X in `Lib.c`. But instead, VS only jumps to the declaration in **Lib.h**.

But if I change the `Lib.c` to remove the macro definition and use the `__declspec(selectany)` directly (see below), pressing F12 on X will jump to **Lib.c** as I expected.

(Lib.c')

```
__declspec(selectany) const int X = 123;
```

Why the usage of macro syntax changes the behavior of Intellisense in Visual Studio?

Comment: Um... Becuse it is based on a pre-compiler with limited capabilities. If you attempt to confuse it - it eventually gets confused. And it is rather easy to confuse, leading to the consequences you describe.

Comment: That's really unfortunate...